# jspm relative url for baseURL

Tags: javascript, jspm

I am starting to use jspm and I am having trouble with the `baseURL` property in config.js
My application ends up at different sub-directories depending on the server its installed on (development, staging live, backup). So in config.js I can not give an absolute url.

I tried setting a variable in the calling html page which is server generated and can be changed based on configuration parameters, but jspm install and jspm bundle both look in config.js for their baseURL instead of in the jspm section  of package.json (which is what i'd expect)

Everything would be just fine if I could put a relative url in that property. But if I try that, then the relative url is translated based on the url of the html page and not the url of config.js (which is what i'd expect). And that wont work because I am using dynamic routing and the url has route parameters embedded in it (pretty url and all)

Comment: can you show us some code, config values (different environments)? Coding before the netz? :)

Comment: :) I thought about that. But I am not sure what part of the code would be relevant. The property in question is baseURL in config.js as in
`System.config({
  baseURL: "Scripts",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
`
I could post my map and path arrays, but I cant see how that would be useful. and the javascript pages that its included in, range from boilerplate test that I copied an pasted from example sites to production pages that were already developed. They all work just fine if I make that property an absolute URL and change it based on environment. but my javascript is served up statically.